# Unable to run gathering stats in parallel?

Tags: oracle, statistics, oracle19c

Our database has one huge table with millions of rows. We had a need to gather its statistics to improve optimizer's cost based plan. To gather it faster, we tried to use parallelism for a table , set table pref 'DEGREE' to

> DBMS_STATS.AUTO_DEGREE

Also, altered session to enable parallel dml. But when we run the following command, gather is not running in parallel, it is being done in one session.

```
dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(i_owner,i_table_name,estimate_percent => dbms_stats.auto_sample_size,no_invalidate => FALSE ,cascade => TRUE);
```

Some online search suggested to remove estimate_percent parameter, but it didn't help. Does anyone know why it is not run in parallel?

The same logic is applied in another schema, but everything works fine there. Is there any priveleges to be granted for this to work? User already has execute privelege on dbms_stat.

Edit:Table has 1 bitmap and 2 normal indexes. I read that bitmap indexes can't be gathered in parallel, could that be the reason? Even if it is, it has 2 normal indexes, shouldn't they be gathered in parallel?

Comment: how did you find "not running in parallel, it is being done in one session" ? The gather should use the pNNN parallel slaves, if they are available. There are a gazillion reasons not to run pq slaves for a task. How are your parallel parameters, what resource manager plan is active? In which resource group is your process?

Comment: Hi @ik_zelf, I look at these views to monitor if parallel slaves are created or not : v$px_process, v$px_process_sysstat, v$pq_sesstat and v$pq_sysstat. Usually when I execute something in parallel, I can see how many servers are allocated, how many are busy, idle or available. Interesting thing I found is that I run the same procedure following the same steps but for another table and it has run in parallel with 56 servers allocated. But for that huge table I have 0s in above views and only one session

Comment: Have these parameters: 
CPU_COUNT= 56;
PARALLEL_MAX_SERVERS  = 1120
PARALLEL_EXECUTION_MESSAGE_SIZE = 25000
PARALLEL_DEGREE_POLICY = MANUAL
PARALLEL_ADAPTIVE_MULTI_USER = FALSE
RESOURCE_MANAGER_PLAN =  SCHEDULER[0x4D78]:DEFAULT_MAINTENANCE_PLAN

Comment: Interesting ... what is the degree defined for the table? (given the fact that it does work for an other table, the resource manager plan won't be a problem.) It's an awful amount for max servers you have (compared to #cpu's)

Comment: Yes ,@ik_zelf, it was a bit strange to me too seeing that amount for max servers, don't know why they set it to this value. Degree of parallelism of a table as it shown in all_tables, is 1. However, I am not sure if this is an issue, since the table for which gather stats worked in parallel also has degree of 1. I am thinking it may be because of a bitmap index of the not-working-in-parallel-table.

Comment: in that case you can try without the cascade and collect the indexes individually.